# Unable to write data in Macro enabled file in R using openxlsx package

Tags: r, excel

When I trying to write data in a Macro enabled file, that excel files gets crashed. Is there any way in R to write data in Macro enabled data keeping the existing data intact. Below is my code:

```
wb <-loadWorkbook("C:/Test/Excel.xlsm")
writeData(wb,df,sheet="sheet1",startRow=2)
saveWorkbook(wb,"C:/Test/Excel.xlsm", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Please add any possible errors/ describe thoroughly the trial and error process

Comment: Does that error occur with xlsx package, e.g. [Populating Excel Macro-enabled cells from R/outside environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31493130/populating-excel-macro-enabled-cells-from-r-outside-environment)

Comment: No this error doesn't occur with xlsx package.

Comment: I tried writing data using write.xlsx() and write.xlsx2(), but it doesn't support .xlsm type file.